# how do I get the script to also check a different dimension?

Tags: javascript

Okay so this code is for a file upload button now this part of the code/javascript checks the dimension of 3000 x 2000 but how do I also get it to check if the image was 2000 x 3000 ? obviously then it would give a result for landscape and portrait images.... ?

```
// Check the image resolution
        if (this.width >= 3000 && this.height >= 2000) {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        } else {
            $("#imageValidationError").show();
            deferred.resolve(false);
        }
    };
```

All The code:

```
 <script>
           function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                        isGoodImage(input.files[0])
            }
        }

        $("#imgInp").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });

        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    function isSupportedBrowser() {
        return window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Image;
    }

    function getSelectedFile() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("imgInp");
        var fileIsSelected = fileInput && fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0];
        if (fileIsSelected)
            return fileInput.files[0];
        else
            return false;
    }

    function isGoodImage(file) {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = function() {
            // Check if image is bad/invalid
            if (this.width + this.height === 0) {
                this.onerror();
                return;
            }

            // Check the image resolution
            if (this.width >= 3000 && this.height >= 2000) {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            } else {
                $("#imageValidationError").show();
                deferred.resolve(false);
            }
        };

        image.onerror = function() {
            $("#noFileError").show();
            deferred.resolve(false);
        }

        image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

        return deferred.promise();
    }

    /** New Code **/
        $("#checkimage").click(function(){


          if (isSupportedBrowser()) {

              var file = getSelectedFile();
              if (!file) {
                  $("#noFileError").show();
                  return;
              }

              isGoodImage(file)
          }
        })
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((this.width >= 3000 && this.height >= 2000) || (this.width >= 2000 && this.height >= 3000)( {
        deferred.resolve(true); }
```

should work.

Comment: do I just place that under the other one or create a similar section to the other one.........

Comment: Just use the if statement I wrote rather than the one in your first line.

Comment: sorry, my computer glitches and didn't display the whole answer so it just looked like you swapped the numbers around haha! thank you!